# How to get a frame off animated png using CSS?

Tags: css

Does CSS provide a way to get a specific frame from animated png (APNG, PNG), or even loop the (A)PNG only from frame A to frame B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APNG isn't a consideration as far as CSS is concerned, most browsers don't even support it (apart from firefox)

What you're best off doing is turning your APNG into a PNG spritesheet, animating it using Javascript and using background-position in CSS to get particular frames.